# updating AWS Datastore table with lots of fields

Tags: flutter, dart, types, dynamic, datastore

I have the following table for storing monthly statistics:

```
type MonthlyStatsTable @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "pOwner" }{ allow: private, operations: [read] }]) {
  pOwner: String! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["year"])
  year: Int!
  m1: Int
  m2: Int
  m3: Int
  m4: Int
  m5: Int
  m6: Int
  m7: Int
  m8: Int
  m9: Int
  m10: Int
  m11: Int
  m12: Int
}
```

Normally I would only update one month at a time, for example September, m9.  I'm trying to avoid a long switch statement to first check which month I want to update before creating my AWS data class.  For example:

```
if ( month9 != '' ){
  MonthlyStatsTable monthlyStats = MonthlyStatsTable(
    pOwner: pOwner,
    year: year,
    m9: month9,
  );
} else if ( month10 != '' ) {...}
```

Is there a better way to handle this?